# Store serial port data in txt

Tags: python

I am trying to make a txt file to store the data that im receiving from USB port, the problem that i have is that the data i send truth bluetooth from my phone to usb port(I use nordic NRF52840), ble uart conexion, when i received the data it considers it as a whole, if i send "hello" and then "how are you?" I receive in txt file: "hellohow are you?" all together as 1 message, it consider everything as 1 string, it doesnt matter if i write \n somewhere.
here is my code:

```css
import serial
archi1=open("datos7.txt",'w')
ser=serial.Serial('COM17',baudrate = 115200, timeout=15)

try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print ("Reading open.")
except:
    print ("Error.")
    exit()

while True:
    data = ser.read(500)
    data = data.replace(b'\r',b'')
    data = data.replace(b'\x1b',b'')
    dataASCII = data.decode("ascii")
    archi1.write('Envio de datos empezado.\n')
    print(data, end='')
    if archi1.write('Los datos obtenidos son:|%s|' % (dataASCII)):
        break
archi1.write('\nEnvio de datos terminado.')
archi1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the following line:

```
data = data.replace(b'\r',b'')
```

You delete the `\r` character, which makes the new lines.

Comment: hello, it doesnt change anything

Comment: Ok, can you try this one `data = data.replace(b'\r',b'\n')` instead?

Comment: it doesnt change,this is what i get on my txt. starting data sending
data received|holaq tal16726262|
finish data sending

Comment: What you write is the content of file2? What is the output of `print(data)` before all the replace statements?

Comment: can you answer my new main answer ?

Comment: If you have another question you should post new question. So, is the original question solved?

Comment: okay, close thread because i cant open another question